# git rebase --editor=/something/other/than/vim? (for easier squashing)

Tags: git, vim, editor, git-rebase

I happily use vim as my default editor for commits, and do not wish to change it. However, when it comes to rebasing, I find myself squashing dozens and dozens of commits which I find much easier with an interactive editor like Textwrangler (substituting "pick" with "squash" in all but the top commit).

**Is there any way to specify an alternate editor for a one-off rebase command?**

I know in vim I can do:

```
:%s/pick/squash/
```

but that has its own minor annoyances.

**EDIT** - as stated in the comments, you can squash all but the top commit very efficiently by going to the 2nd line and executing

```
:,$s/pick/squash/
```

(note the comma and dollar are different to the original)

Comment: In vim, you can do `:,$s/pick/squash/` which will change all occurrences from the *current line* through to the end of the file.

Comment: That's a great tip, thanks Greg. Yes, that was the "minor annoyance" I was alluding to.

Comment: Assuming you have an up to date vim version or have install Tim Pope's vim-git plugin, you can use the `:Cycle` or `:Squash` commands. You may even want to use a mapping. Maybe use the `:global` command: `:+,$g/./Squash`

Comment: May I ask what :Cycle and :Squash do? I'm having trouble finding the documentation for those commands.

Comment: I also use "marks" heavily.  Go to the first line you want to change, type `ma` (set mark `a`), go to the last you want to change, type `:'a,.s/this/that/`.  Single quote followed by a mark-letter means "the line where that mark is set".

Comment: `:Cycle` will cycle through the rebase options: `pick`, `squash`, `edit`, `rework`, and `fixup`. `:Squash` will mark a line as `squash`. Take a look at `e $VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/gitrebase.vim` for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the info Peter, and torek.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Try adding the `GIT_EDITOR` environment variable before your command, like so:

```
GIT_EDITOR=<editor of choice> git rebase <...>
```

For example, to use `nano` I would type:

```
GIT_EDITOR=nano git rebase -i abcdef1234
```

Comment: Since you aren't exporting it, does that variable value get reset when the command terminates? (that would be ideal, but I'm guessing you need to reset it manually)

Comment: The variable is only set for that one command invocation. Try running `git rebase` again without `GIT_EDITOR` and you'll use your default editor again.

Comment: Awesome, this is the right answer then. Though I think my fears of learning a bit more vim were irrational

Comment: Awesome indeed. For some reason my ancient server-side OS defaulted to `vi` instead of `vim` --so now I know how to perma-fix this.

Comment: This helped me a lot thanks, i believe a lot of people are looking for `GIT_EDITOR=nano git rebase -i @~9` this will show your last nine commits and you should be able to modify them.

Comment: For visual code use GIT_EDITOR="code --wait" git rebase -i abfa452

Comment: Just put this in your env and it's perfect yup

Answer (score 18):

There is an even better option for all your interactive rebase.

https://github.com/sjurba/rebase-editor

It is a custom CLI app written in node specifically for interactive rebase.

To install:

```
npm install -g rebase-editor
git config --global sequence.editor rebase-editor
```

Or with yarn:

```
yarn global add rebase-editor
git config --global sequence.editor rebase-editor
```

Comment: dang this tool is awesome sauce

Comment: This tool is now required part of my setup. Being able to select each action with the single press of a key makes "git rebase" a teachable process.

Comment: I went to this tool's documentation with the intension to use it, but unfortunately this doesn't work with git-bash on windows (https://github.com/sjurba/rebase-editor/issues/7). 
Tried the hack `git config --global sequence.editor 'winpty rebase-editor.cmd'`, but that didn't work out for me. Can't put much time in this so will live with the vim editor on gitbash for now.

Answer (score 1):

With Git 2.40 (Q1 2023), just like "[`git var GIT_EDITOR`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/48475f43a0a92697999d0189d7d4bfd1d1841299/Documentation/git-var.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-var))</sup>" abstracts the complex logic to choose which editor gets used behind it, "`git var`" now give support to `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR`.

See [commit 4c3dd93](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4c3dd9304e49402bd4ee19dfaa4c21d0217fb582) (17 Dec 2022) by [Sean Allred (`vermiculus`)](https://github.com/vermiculus).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 48475f4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/48475f43a0a92697999d0189d7d4bfd1d1841299), 28 Dec 2022)</sup>

> ### [`var`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4c3dd9304e49402bd4ee19dfaa4c21d0217fb582): add `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR` variable
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Sean Allred</sup>

> The editor program used by Git when editing the sequencer "todo" file is determined by examining a few environment variables and also affected by configuration variables.
> Introduce "[`git var GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4c3dd9304e49402bd4ee19dfaa4c21d0217fb582/Documentation/git-var.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-var))</sup>" to give users access to the final result of the logic without having to know the exact details.
>
> This is very similar in spirit to [44fcb49](https://github.com/git/git/commit/44fcb4977cbae67f4698306ccfe982420ceebcbf) (Teach `git var` about `GIT_EDITOR`, 2009-11-11, Git v1.6.6-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/376f39fbea0dfb31402abda878a7b0018f6a6161)) that introduced "`git var GIT_EDITOR`".

`git var` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4c3dd9304e49402bd4ee19dfaa4c21d0217fb582/Documentation/git-var.txt#L53-L60):

> ### `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR`
>
> Text editor used to edit the 'todo' file while running `git rebase -i`. Like `GIT_EDITOR`, the value is meant to be interpreted by
> the shell when it is used.
>
> The order of preference is:
>
> - the
>   `$GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR` environment variable, then
> - `sequence.editor` configuration, and then
> - the value of `git var GIT_EDITOR`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have set an interactive editor for rebases. However, I found it could not do something I wanted it to, so in the case that I want to specify an alternative editor for the occasional invocation, the following works:

```
git -c sequence.editor=vim rebase -i upstream/main
```

The `-c sequence.editor=<value>` sets the value of the `sequence.editor` config key for that single command. You can use this syntax for any command, and it comes in handy from time to time.

Comment: Works like a charm for vscode, thanks: `git -c sequence.editor="code --wait" rebase -i --autostash origin/dev`