# Why does Git merge VIM screen sometimes appear

Tags: git, vim

Sometimes when I attempt to do a git pull from a branch, github will create the message:

```
"please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary, 
especially if it merges an updated upstream into a topic branch."
```

It will then require me to enter special commands like :wq to complete the merge. However, other times the merge will simply go through without issue or with it asking me to resolve conflicts.

I know this thread discusses how to exit the issue:

[Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary, especially if it merges an updated upstream into a topic branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19085807/please-enter-a-commit-message-to-explain-why-this-merge-is-necessary-especially)

But my question is why does this happen in git to begin with?

Comment: You might want to elaborate more on the case where the merge completes with no issue, or the case where there are merge conflicts.  In the former case, I might guess that is happening when the merge is just a fast-forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes from [`builtin/merge.c#merge_editor_comment()`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2d3b1c576c85b7f5db1f418907af00ab88e0c303/builtin/merge.c#L794-L799), used in [`builtin/merge.c#prepare_to_commit()`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2d3b1c576c85b7f5db1f418907af00ab88e0c303/builtin/merge.c#L794-L810), in order to remind the user what he/she is supposed to use the editor for.
It is called even with [`builtin/merge.c#merge_trivial()`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2d3b1c576c85b7f5db1f418907af00ab88e0c303/builtin/merge.c#L837-L853).

All the details for that message are in "[Git error while updating a repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33289642/6309)".

Note: `:wq` is only because your [`core.editor`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-coreeditor) configuration must be [set to `vi`/`vim` by default](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-var#git-var-GITEDITOR).
You can [use other editors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19713991/6309).